# Where can I read more about adventures of characters from "The First Law" (J. Abercrombie)

Tags: joe-abercrombie

I just finished the *[First Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_First_Law)* trilogy by [Joe Abercrombie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Abercrombie) and was wondering whether I can read more about adventures of:

- Sand dan Glokta
- Ferro
- Bayaz & Kahul

in his other books?

I know that Bayaz appears in *[Best Served Cold](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?878564)* and *[The Heroes*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1156610) (didn't read them yet) but I'm under impression that both of these books are placed in the same world but not related to story in *The First Law*.

I quite liked characters from *The First Law* so would like to read more about them rather than reading some standalone story... but is it possible, does Glokta, Ferro or story of Bayaz and Kahul appears in other Joe Abercrombie books?

If you can please just list where I can find out more about this characters...no spoilers please :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Abercombie has written five novels (including the first law trilogy) and two short stories.

Glokta and Ferro haven't appeared in any of the other books and short stories, though others from the trilogy do appear in *The Heroes*, namely *Bremer van Grost, Bayaz, Black Dow* and *Kahul*.

You would probably like both *Best Served Cold* and *The Heroes* if you liked *The First Law* trilogy, so I would say go ahead and read them. The newer books are unconnected in the sense that they don't carry the same threads from the original trilogy forward, but instead they launch new threads about characters not seen or not important before. These new threads tie in with the old ones and take place against similar backdrops (the secret war between the two sides). Future stories merging all the threads together seems likely (in Malazan style).

Comment: Red Country is the sixth novel and features a few characters from The First Law trilogy. Also, Joe Abercombie has stated that he is writing another trilogy set in world and that he just finished volume two.